# Find paragraph formatting and replace it with a style

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a huge document which was converted to Word from a pdf.  I am attempting to use the "format paragraph" option within the "find and replace" feature to find paragraphs that meet certain parameters: i.e., "alignment" = left; "left indent" = 0.08; "right indent" = 0.02; "special first line indent" = 0.28; "spacing before" = 0; "spacing after" = 0; "line spacing" = multiple 1.04.  I want to replace all instances of the above paragraph parameters with a style "Body Text First Indent .5".

All I have ever received in response is "No Results Found".  Ordinarily I would simply "find" the "normal" style and "replace" it with the the desired style, but in this instance, **everything** is currently styled as "normal".

Is this even possible?  If yes - I would greatly appreciate knowing what it is that I am missing.  With hopes that I have clearly explained the situation, I remain..

Sincerely - Mitch

Comment: Does this answer the question: Normally you would enter Find and Replace, click More, click "Find what", click Format to specify your Paragraph and Font values. Do the same after clicking "Replace with". It might be better to replace by a created new style of yours for future changes.

Comment: I very much appreciate your response, Harry.  Rather than reiterate my initial question, what are the chances that you could give it a try?  That may lead to a better explanation of what it is that I am attempting to accomplish.  For example, do a "find" for paragraphs reflecting a particular set of parameters (paragraph parameters that actually exist) with an eye toward "replacing" those paragraphs with an actual "style".  "Finding/isolating" the paragraphs fitting the parameters is the issue, not the "style replacement" .  Thanks so very much for your attempt at assisting.  Mitch

Comment: You could post a small fragment as a document for me to have a look. (Add to any future comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)